# How to get guild object using guild ID

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I want to change the icon of a specific guild that my bot is in. To do so, I need to use the `guild.setIcon()` method. I already have the guild's ID but I don't know how I should go about turning it into an object that I can use.

The `guildId` constant is stored as a string in config.json.

Here is my index.js, where I'm trying to run the code.

```
// Require the necessary discord.js classes
const { Client, Collection, Intents } = require("discord.js");
const { token, guildId } = require("./config.json");
const fs = require("fs");

// Create a new client instance
const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS] });

client.commands = new Collection();
const commandFiles = fs
  .readdirSync("./commands")
  .filter((file) => file.endsWith(".js"));

for (const file of commandFiles) {
  const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
  client.commands.set(command.data.name, command);
}

const eventFiles = fs
  .readdirSync("./events")
  .filter((file) => file.endsWith(".js"));

for (const file of eventFiles) {
  const event = require(`./events/${file}`);
  if (event.once) {
    client.once(event.name, (...args) => event.execute(...args));
  } else {
    client.on(event.name, (...args) => event.execute(...args));
  }
}

client.on("interactionCreate", async (interaction) => {
  if (!interaction.isCommand()) return;

  const command = client.commands.get(interaction.commandName);

  if (!command) return;

  try {
    await command.execute(interaction);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    await interaction.reply({
      content: "There was an error while executing this command!",
      ephemeral: true,
    });
  }
});

client.login(token);

const myGuild = client.guilds.cache.get(guildId)
myGuild.setIcon("./images/image.png");
```

The error I get is

```
myGuild.setIcon("./images/image.png");
        ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'setIcon')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do this in an event. No guilds are cached until the client is ready

```js
client.on("ready", async () => {
  const myGuild = client.guilds.cache.get(guildId)
  await myGuild.setIcon("./images/image.png")
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Your issues comes from the fact that you're trying to get the guild from your bot cache, but he doesn't have it in it's cache

First, you have to wait for your bot to be successfully connected
Then, you're not supposed to read from the cache directly, use the GuildManager methods (here you need [`fetch`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildManager?scrollTo=fetch))

to summarize, replace the 2 lasts lines of your `index.js` by

```js
client.on("ready", async () => {
    const myGuild = await client.guilds.fetch(guildId)
    myGuild.setIcon("./images/image.png")
})
```

Comment: No need to fetch the guild, all guilds the bot is in are always cached. It's just an unnecessary API request

Comment: @MrMythical in that case, replace fetch with resolve which is synchronous https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildManager?scrollTo=resolve

Comment: Why change that part of the OP's code? Getting from cache is just fine. Note that .resolve also just gets from cache

Comment: @MrMythical it's a good practice to learn to avoid it since it works here because guilds are prefetched, but can fail for channels or messages