# how can i get guild by id in discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I can't get the guild from its id in discord.js.

This is what I tried:

```js
function getGuildById(ID) {
    return client.guilds.cache.get("1033299353445605396");
}
```

The function returns `undefined`.

Comment: Try fetching the guild: `await client.guilds.fetch(ID)`. You will have to make the function asynchronous

Comment: You'll need to call this function once the `client` is ready, in an event handler. Where do you try to execute it?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Search is always your best friend; did you saw [the link that [Oliver Nybo provided]
(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70306278/how-to-get-guild-object-using-guild-id)? It is always faster than wait for an answer...

Answer (score 2):

Due to the way that discord.js is designed (and most Discord API libraries in general), when your bot connects to Discord's Gateway, it gets sent a bunch of information about the state of the guilds it is in. You also need to enable the `GUILDS` intent for the gateway to send that information when you connect.

Getting a Guild from discord.js' cache will fail if such guild hasn't been cached yet. This can happen both if you don't enable the right intents, or if you try to `#.cache.get(id)` before the gateway has finished sending information.

You can solve this in two ways:

#### 1. Waiting for the client to be ready before getting the Guild from cache

If you really want to use `#.cache.get()`, you need to run it after the `ready` event has been fired by the client.

```js
client.on('ready', () => {
  // ...
  const guild = client.guilds.cache.get(guildId)
  // ...
})
```

#### 2. Fetching the Guild instead

As a safer alternative, you can use `client.guilds.fetch()`, which will return you the Guild if it has already been cached, or fetch it from the API if it hasn't.

```js
const guild = await client.guilds.fetch(guildId)
```